# Combine bag of words for multiple documents

Tags: python, word-count

I have multiple documents, for this example lets say 3.
They each contain several different words separated by a space. Now I want to count all the words per document and put it in a matrix or dataframe. So I have the specific Document as a row, each word as a column, and the number of occurences as the number in the dataframe. See example below

```
Doc1 = "a b c d"
Doc2 = "a c e f"
Doc3 = "a e f f"


data = {'a': [1,1,1],
        'b': [1,0,0],
        'c': [1,1,0],
        'd': [1,0,0],
        'e': [0,1,1],
        'f': [0,1,2],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc1 = "a b c d"
doc2 = "a c e f"
doc3 = "a e f f"

docs = [doc1, doc2, doc3]

data = {}

for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    for word in doc.split():
        val = data.get(word, [0] * len(docs))
        val[i] += 1
        data[word] = val
print(data)

# Alternative

data = {}
for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    for word in doc.split():
        try:
            data[word][i] += 1
        except KeyError:
            data[word] = [0 if i != j else 1 for j in range(len(docs))]
print(data)
```